# In SQL, how can I prevent values being inserted where the foreign key is not necessarily equal, but contained within them?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I prevent values being added to a field based on similar values in a field in another table?

I have two tables:

The first, I have area codes: e.g. 0112, 0152, 01365, 098.

The second, I have call charge prefixes: 011, 015, 0136, 09.

I want to prevent values being inserted into the first table should any value in the second table be 'contained'.  Therefore, 0112 can be inserted because it contains '011'.  Note: prefixes and area codes vary in length.  These are VARCHAR(2).

Best regards.

Comment: You do it in a business logic.

Comment: Is the area code always one character shorter than the charge prefix?

Answer (score 0):

As Anri said, do it in business logic.

If it has to be purely in sql you could create a trigger which wouldn't prevent from being added but would delete the record just after inserting.  I wouldn't recommend this approach but if you had to do it purely in sql then this might be an option.

Comment: I'd suggest business logic with a trigger acting as a safeguard.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a prefix table and a suffix table where the suffix table has a foreign key pointing to the primary key of the prefix table.

So your prefix would contain something like

```
id   prefix
---- -------
1    011
2    015
3    0136
4    09
```

and the suffix table would look like this

```
id   prefixid suffix
---- -------- --------
1    1        2
2    2        2
3    3        5
4    4        8
```

Not sure I particularly like the design but it's one way of ensuring that the prefix part of your area code is valid.

Another option might be to use a check constraint to verify that the first part of your area code is in the allowed list of prefixes. You would need to use a wildcard on the end of your prefixes within the check constraint.